# AS3.0 facebook api: getSession() returns null for user name

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook

I'm starting a facebook app using iframe method.
I am using flex and so far I am able to connect to fb (login and out). Now I am trying to retrieve current logged in user name. In the document I see this function is what I need. Facebook.getSession().
A tutorial in adobe site uses desktop api and it works for desktop (AIR app) but not for web app. (yes, i fixed Facebook.getSession() instead of FacebookDesktop.getSession();

Also, I am able to see the uid but not the user. User returns null. I am guessing this is because uid is a string and user is an object. But on the desktop app, FacebookDesktop.getSession().user.name returns the name perfectly. but on the web, it does not.

Any help on this would be appreciated because I have been banging my head on this for 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that when you use FacebookDesktop to log in, it automatically makes an API call to the me object to get the information about the user.  For some reason the Facebook class does not do this for you.  In your login handler, you have make the call.  So your login handler will contain something like:

```
if (success)
{
    Facebook.api("/me", api_getMeHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the /ME object you can directly read the user name:

```
protected function api_getMeHandler(result:Object,fail:Object):void{
            // load name and birthday
            var fbName:String=""; 
            if( result.name != null) {
                fbName = result.name; 
                bottomLabel.text = fbName + "Logged IN";
            }     
            else {                
                bottomLabel.text = "User Name NULL";
            }
        }
```

I am working with the 1.5 Version, which includes the AS class wrapper for JS.